# jQuery perfomance when trying to hide rows in table

Tags: jquery

i have the performance problem.
I have a table with 500 rows for example, i try to hide column in it, and spend near 10seconds on waiting.

```
<table>
<thead>
<th class="c1">ColumnName1</th>
<th class="c2">ColumnName2</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td class="c1">data</td>
<td class="c2">data</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i use smth like

```
jQuery('.c2').hide();
```

Can anybody give me advice how to improve speed in this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: How long does it take for 50 lines ?

Comment: I test it in chrome, 50 lines hm... <1sec

Answer (score 1):

Five hundred rows is quite a lot, so I understand that you might run in to some performance issues. You can start of by trying to provide a more specific selector. Try this for instance:

```
jQuery('td.c2').hide();
```

Or add an ID to your table, to make it even more specific

```
jQuery('#yourTableId td.c2').hide();
```

You might also find this article about jQuery selector performance useful:

- [jQuery Performance Rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/)

Based on what is being said in that article, you would probably be best of doing something like this:

```
jQuery("#yourTableId").find("td.c2").hide();

// Or if you intend to do more than one operation on your set of elements, 
// cache the set of elements in a variable, so that the selector is only run once

var myElements = jQuery("#yourTableId").find("td.c2");
myElements.hide();
myElements.remove(); // Do some other stuff to your elements

// Or make use of the chaining
jQuery("#yourTableId").find("td.c2").hide().remove();
```

Comment: Thanx, i try to use it now, and after that i say results.

Answer (score 0):

first jQuery dom traversing is faster when you specify id element

```
$("#myTable .c2").hide();
```

or add context

```
$('.class', '#class-container').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a bit more faster if you first select the table by ID and then use .find(). Selecting the table will set a context for the search instead of going through the whole document.

You can also preprend the tagName when selecting by class.

```
$("#myTable").find('td.c2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use more effective selectors.
For example, put an id on your table and search per each row, for the td with class c2.

```
jQuery("#table_id > tr > td.c2").hide();
```

Using the selector ">" tells jQuery to select the direct children and not search all tags within the parent.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on different things, like:

- the browser you are testing with (Internet Explorer 7 and 8 is much slower than Chrome and Mozilla in terms of rendering and the JS engine overall)
- the amount of html that needs to be hidden for each column

You should probably think of solving this problem on server side (if you are using ASP, JSP, PHP, etc.) and sending back the manipulated HTML. Nowadays people think that everything can be handled with pure javascript. Even though modern web browsers are becoming faster and faster, there are still use cases where "traditional" server side web development is the way to go.

Another thing (just something for you to test):
Maybe you can try using `visibility: collapse` instead of `display: none` (which is used by jQuery when calling `hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

it's me again.)
I want to talk about how i decide this problem
I need to improve performance while i work with confluence and what i do.

in this action i generate json with html code then send it back
this code was a delta of table depens on filter parameters. And i also use advantages of of confluence cache. The last perfomanse result is less then 100ms. Bingo))
Thnx all for replies

p.s. 2Christofer Eliasson
i try to use performance rules but it not improve performance so much but anyway thanks for usefull link. i'll try to use this good practice in future)